# Как вставить объект(панель) в html из html?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, html5

Пробовал через iframe но ссылки отображались внутри фрейма. Делаю для того что бы не переписывать каждый файл в случае изменение панели.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно добавить `target="_top"` к ссылке, тогда она будет открывать ссылку не внутри `iframe`, а менять url всей страницы:

```
<a href="http://link.domain" target="_top">Click me</a>
```